# Задача на вложенный вопрос SQL или JOIN. Нужна помощь

Tags: sql, sql-server, запрос

**Есть две таблицы**

```
Create table [employees]
(
Persona_id, Name, Dates_birthday, Job_position, Experience, Location_Id
)
```

```
Create table [location]
( Location_ID, City, Address, Desk
)
```

Нужно вывести местоположение самого старшего по возрасту сотрудника. 
**Через вложенный селект или join уже не так важно**.

Пробовал так, но он выдает не ту инфу. ПОМОГИТЕ разобраться и верно составить запрос:

```
Select min(Dates_Birthday) as dr, l.City from [employees] e
Left join [location] l on e. location_ID=l. location_ID
Group by city, dates_birthday 
Having count(*) >1
```

Comment: вам тут не группировка с минимумом нужна а сортировка по возрасту и первая строка выборки

Comment: а если таковых (что в целом верно) сотрудников может быт несколько, то подзапрос на максимальный возраст.

Comment: У меня в Dates_birthday введена дата рождения, а не возраст. 
Можете воспроизвести запрос ваш, пожалуйста .

Comment: чем больше дата рождения, тем меньше возраст, как ни странно, это верно и в обратную сторону.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно, например, так:

```
Create table employees (
    Persona_id, Name, Dates_birthday, Job_position, Experience, Location_Id
);

Create table location (
    Location_ID, City, Address, Desk
);

insert into employees values(1, 'John', 1, 'laborer', 1, 1);
insert into employees values(2, 'Ivan', 2, 'laborer', 1, 2);

insert into location values(1, 'SPb', 'Nevsky pr.', 'desk');
insert into location values(2, 'Moscow', 'Red sq.', 'desk');

select l.city, l.address 
from location l 
where l.Location_Id = (
    select TOP 1 e.Location_Id from employees e ORDER BY e.Dates_birthday ASC
);
```

Выведет:

> SPb|Nevsky pr.

Comment: на MS SQL "limit" не работает

Comment: Попробуйте `TOP 1` (ответ обновил). И указывайте в вопросе реализацию БД через метки - так больше вероятность получить сразу работающий ответ)

Comment: спасибо за помощь